# Running MS-Access macro using batch file when not logged in

Tags: ms-access, macros, batch-file, export

I have the following set up on a server

1. Two MS-Access queries
2. Exported the data from the queries and saved the export steps
3. Created a macro to run these export steps then exit MS-Access
4. Created a batch file to open ms-access and run the macro

   - This works fine and dandy if I log into the server and double click the batch file, but if I set up a scheduled task to "run even if not logged in" then the ms-access macro doesn't seem to run....so it seems like access is never ran.

Does anyone have any ideas?  Can you do this sort of process when "not logged in"?  Is there something else I need to do?  I am really stuck and need to have this automated.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you may need different tags. Is the MS Access task the only one that fails in this way? Have you read http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721846.aspx?

Comment: Yes, the access task is the only one that fails.  There is another task that moves some text files to an FTP server using a batch file and that one runs successfully.

Comment: You might like to read http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1646920. Have you considered writing your code in VB Script and running that?

Answer (score 1):

**My best guess is that you are trying to access a mapped network location that is not available.**

Many networks have logon scripts that map network drives to local drive letters.  These logon scripts are not run when you set up a scheduled task to "run even if not logged on."

So if you either:

**A**) are exporting your query results to a file on a mapped network drive (ie, N:\MyExport.txt) or,
**B**) have one or more tables in the source of your query that are linked to .mdb's on mapped network drives (ie, `CurrentDb.Tables("MyTable").Connect = "N:\MyBackend.mdb"`)

then the process will fail.

If you are expecting to see an error message when you log on, you won't see one because the Access process is not visible when run through a scheduled task.  However, if you go to Task Manager you should see an MSACCESS.EXE process listed.

---

If this is the problem there are two possible workarounds:

1. Use UNC paths (ie, `\\fileserver\folder\MyExport.txt` instead of `N:\MyExport.txt`)
2. Set up your scheduled task to run a batch file that:

   1. maps the network drives using `NET USE` commands
   2. opens your MS Access program with the appropriate command line arguments